# Intent not fired in device but works fine in simulator?

Tags: actions-on-google

I am developing action for assistant. I have intent in dialogflow that is fired correctly in simulator but does not get fired in a real device rather fallback intent is triggered ? 
What puzzles me more is the intent works fine with one email id but does not work with another email id on the same device ?
I highly doubt the issue arising from language preferences.

Answer (score 3):

It is really difficult to diagnose issues like this with only generic information. To really help, we'd need to see specifics of the Intent and examples where it doesn't get triggered where you expect it to. But a few things to consider:

- If the sample phrase uses homonyms like "to/two/too" or "four/for", it can be picked up incorrectly.
- You don't indicate if this is spoken or typed where you have the problem. You may want to look at the entries at https://myactivity.google.com/ to see how it hears what you're saying.
- Check the Dialogflow "History" section to see if it provides any guidance on what it is getting and why it is choosing the fallback intent.